# V8 Exposing classes but restricting that in particular code

Tags: javascript, c++, sandbox, v8

I am currently working with V8 in a C++ Environment. I am making a server client system so that people can send JS to a server and have it run on the server. It works as expected but I am having a pickle figuring out how to make a sandbox environment. I am trying to avoid just blacklisting function names from client code.

The structure I am going for has two types of files:

**JS Library Files:** Used to write js libraries for use in the sandbox. Has access to C++ classes that have been exposed to V8. Functions defined in this file will be accessible to the clients.

**Sandbox:** This will be able to access functions that are defined in the JS Library Files but won't have access to the C++ classes that were exposed to V8.

This would allow "admins" of the system to write JS library files using the EXTREMELY powerful exposed C++ classes but would restrict the clients to only using functions defined in the lib files and whatever they define themselves.

If that isn't fully clear, here is an example scenario:

JS Library File (isInNationLib.js):

```
function isInAmerica(clientName) {
    var ip = ipByClientName(clientName);
    //use the ip to find if the client is in America
}
```

Client File:

```
#include "isInNationLib"
function getNationality(clientName) {
    if (isInAmerica(clientName)) {
        return "American";
    }
    etc...
}
```

From the example above, the client should never have access to ipByClientName for security reasons. ipByClientName would be a C++ function exposed to V8. This particular example isn't going to be in my project but it showcases the security aspects of the problem.

Comment: By blacklisting, you mean searching client code for the actual string representing the illegal function and rejecting?  Ya, that won't work.

Comment: I know, but I can't think of any other way to do it.

Comment: Whitelist.  Replace calls in permitted code with crypto strong unique name?  Defeat requires hostile code to get source or someine else's call or enumerate entry points or somesuch.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a context, you specify what is added to that context -- either by setting it in the `ObjectTemplate` when you create the context or by calling `Set` on the global object of the context afterwards.

Make two `contexts`, one where the restricted stuff is accessible, and one where it isn't and route the incoming javascript to the appropriate context based on whatever authorization mechanisms you have in place.